# Can Guice inject Scala objects

Tags: scala, guice

In Scala, can I use [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/) to inject Scala `object`s?

For example, can I inject into `s` in the following object?

```scala
object GuiceSpec {
  @Inject
  val s: String = null

  def get() = s
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Some research on Google revealed that you can accomplish this as follows (the code that follows is a [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org) unit test):

```scala
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatest.matchers.MustMatchers
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner
import com.google.inject.Inject
import com.google.inject.Module
import com.google.inject.Binder
import com.google.inject.Guice
import uk.me.lings.scalaguice.ScalaModule

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class GuiceSpec extends WordSpec with MustMatchers {

  "Guice" must {
    "inject into Scala objects" in {
      val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ScalaModule() {
        def configure() {
          bind[String].toInstance("foo")
          bind[GuiceSpec.type].toInstance(GuiceSpec)
        }
      })
      injector.getInstance(classOf[String]) must equal("foo")
      GuiceSpec.get must equal("foo")
    }
  }
}

object GuiceSpec {
  @Inject
  var s: String = null

  def get() = s
}
```

This assumes you are using [scala-guice](https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice) and [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org).

Comment: the answer in the below post suggests it is not possible to inject dependencies in scala object. any idea about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100534/can-we-use-google-guice-di-with-a-scala-object-instead-of-a-scala-class-in-play

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct, but if you don't want to use `ScalaGuice` Extensions, you can do the following:

```scala
val injector = Guice.createInjector(new ScalaModule() {
    def configure() {
      bind[String].toInstance("foo")
    }

    @Provides
    def guiceSpecProvider: GuiceSpec.type = GuiceSpec
  })
```

Comment: Instead of @Provides you can simply add requestInjection(guideSpec) in configure()