# Can we use Google Guice DI with a Scala Object instead of a Scala class in Play 2.4 with scala

Tags: scala, playframework, guice, ehcache

Our application is built on **Play 2.4 with Scala 2.11 and Akka**. 
Cache is used heavily in our application.We use Play's default **EhCache** for caching.

We currently use the **Cache object**(play.api.cache.Cache) for Caching

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.cache.Cache

object SampleDAO extends TableQuery(new SampleTable(_)) with SQLWrapper {
  def get(id: String) : Future[Sample] = {
    val cacheKey = // our code to generate a unique cache key
    Cache.getOrElse[Future[[Sample]](cacheKey) {
      db.run(this.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
    }
  }
}
```

Now with Play 2.4 we plan to make use of the inbuilt **Google Guice DI** support. Below is a sample example provided by the Play 2.4 docs

```
import play.api.cache._
import play.api.mvc._
import javax.inject.Inject

class Application @Inject() (cache: CacheApi) extends Controller {

}
```

The above example inserts **dependency** into a **Scala class constructor**. 
But in our code **SampleDAO is a Scala object but not class** .

So now Is it **possible to implement Google Guice DI with A scala object** instead of a scala class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to inject objects in guice. Make your `SampleDAO` a class instead, where you inject `CacheApi`. Then inject your new DAO class in your controllers. You can additionally annotate `SampleDAO` with `@Singleton`. This will ensure `SampleDAO` will be instantiated only once. The whole thing would look something like this:

**DAO**

```
@Singleton
class SampleDAO @Inject()(cache: CacheApi) extends TableQuery(new SampleTable(_)) with SQLWrapper {
  // db and cache stuff
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Application @Inject()(sampleDAO: SampleDAO) extends Controller {
  // controller stuff
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to bind the the DAO and its Implementation as well? Just in case someone is wondering as well!

Comment: @GeorgeNikolaides If separating interface and implementation, then yes. For reasons of simplicity there is no separate interface in the example above. That's why the class (implementation) is injected directly.

Comment: the answer in the below link suggests it is possible to inject dependencies in a Scala object.. any idea about this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791815/can-guice-inject-scala-objects

Comment: @mig-foxbat this seems to be rather hacky to me. Assigning `null` to a val variable is bad practice an in the context of Scala also useless. You must not reassign val in Scala. In the example `val s` will be reassigned by Guice using reflection. This is like you were reassigning a final variable in Java. A don't do. Anyway, what's your use case? Can't you just use a class instead?

Comment: @Roman if I have to convert my object to class then I will have to change my other objects that refer my target object to classes and this creates a ripple effect. And I agree with your point of Injecting in object esp val is not a recommended practice and should be used sparingly.