# How can I access to a method in ServiceImpl from view helpers?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have  a method that retrieves the blog posts based on a user. And I would like to make use of it in my view helpers, but can’t figure out how.

The code of BlogServiceImpl is like this:

```
class BlogServiceImpl @Inject() (blogDAO: BlogDAO, clock: Clock) extends BlogService {
  def retrieve(user: User): Future[Seq[Blog]] = blogDAO.find(user)
}
```

And here is the BlogController that uses the method.

```
  def view: Action[AnyContent] = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
    blogService.retrieve(request.identity).map { blogSeq =>
      Ok(views.html.blog.blog(request.identity, BlogForm.form, blogSeq))
    }
```

I wish I could write the code like below. but since it’s an object not a class, I can’t inject BlogService and thus, no way to access it. What is the best solution for problems like this?

```
object Helpers {

  def postTitle(user: User) = {
   val post: Future[Option[Blog]] = blogService.retrieve(user).headOption
   Await.ready(post, Duration.Inf).value.get {
     case Success(Some(pst) => pst
     case Success(None) => None
   }

  some other helper methods...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274533/inject-in-scala-object
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100534/can-we-use-google-guice-di-with-a-scala-object-instead-of-a-scala-class-in-play

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin it seems like an only way to go. Thanks!