# Inject in scala object

Tags: scala, playframework, guice

I'm using Play framework 2.5 and try to inject WSClient in a scala object used in my controllers.

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

    object MyObject {

        @Inject
        var ws: WSClient = null

        def doSomething() = { // use wsclient }

    }
```

I use MyObject in several controllers and when calling doSomething() wsclient is null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define `MyObject` as class and inject wsclient to it:

```
class MyObject @Inject()(ws: WSClient) {
    def doSomething() = { /* use wsclient */ }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible with object ?  I must define a class ?

Comment: According to my knowledge injecting to object is only possible during Play module initilization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791815/can-guice-inject-scala-objects

Comment: Is it possible to use something like this to @Inject Java classes with the Inversion-of-Control mentality?

Comment: how this solve OP? OP now have to create instance of MyObject since it's a class now

Comment: It's not possible. But for anyone finding this, one pattern I've found that works is to use a companion object with an apply method that takes in the dependencies, and returns an instance of the class. In the Companion object, make sure only one instance of that class is ever created. That way when you call the companion object it will create it on the first call, and then reuse that instance. It's the only pure DI workaround I've been able to come up with.