# Is there any reason to use classes vs object at all in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Just a precursor, I'm coming from a Java background and am fairly new to Scala. As I develop more in Scala and try to become more FP oriented, I realize I can make almost all of my code: functions (and even methods?) contained in Objects (with a sprinkling of case classes where needed). In that case - is there any use at all for regular classes?

Comment: IMHO this question will be very opinion based, however I will not flag it yet, to see what other think first. Anyways, my opinion _(the irony is big)_ regarding this is that they are still useful depending on what you want. Case classes will give you identity by value _(which is great)_ but if you need reference equality _(for nay reason)_ then having regular classes is useful. Also, case classes generate a lot of boiler plate code, which very useful when needed, may make the byte code too big if used everywhere. Finally implicit classes and value classes work great as normal classes.

Comment: If you are coming from a Java background, perhaps an analogy would help. How would you answer this question: "Is there any reason to use non-static methods in Java?"

Comment: Objects don't have same level of support as Classes have for eg: Dependency Injection has its own constraints on objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274533/inject-in-scala-object

Comment: There's always the [principle of least power](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/StrategicScalaStylePrincipleofLeastPower.html).

Answer (score 3):

```
//traits (interfaces) without implementation are perfectly valid from FP standpoint
//it's just a bag of named functions
trait A {
  def foo(s: String): Int
}

//Ok, you can implement a trait without declaring a class
object Obj extends A {
  override def foo(s: String): Int = s.length
}

//But if you want your function to be parametrized then classes are useful
//You can think of classes as partially aplied functions in FP sense 
class Clz(param: String) extends A {
  override def foo(s: String): Int = (param + s).length
}
```