# How to inject Scala classes in objects?

Tags: scala, guice

I want to use a singleton class in a Scala companion object but I am using `Guice` dependency injection and, as far as I know, it has no explicit usage in these scenarios.

As an example, let's say we have Singleton (using Guice) class as follows:

```
@Singleton
class Foo Inject()(foo2: Foo2) { 
    def func = { ... }
}
```

I can use it in other classes as:

```
class MyClass Inject()(foo: Foo) { 
   foo.func()
}
```

What about objects? I need to create an instance with `new` as:

```
object MyObject { 
   val foo2 = new Foo2()
   val foo = new Foo(foo2)
   foo.func()
}
```

In this case, does `Foo` still have just one instance? I mean, does `new Foo(foo2)` return the same instance as Guice returns in `@Inject()(foo: Foo)`?

By the way, there are already questions about this (e.g., [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274533/inject-in-scala-object)) but I want to use objects and access the singleton instances inside them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, does Foo still have just one instance? I mean, does new Foo(foo2) return the same instance as Guice returns in @Inject()(foo: Foo)?

No. Just as if you call `new Foo(...)` elsewhere. My suggestion would just be not to mix it; if you want to use Guice's instances inside `MyObject`, make it a Guice singleton class as well. Or make `Foo` an `object`, you can still access it from Guice-using classes.

If you really need it, the way I can think of is really ugly; to store the `Injector` from your `main` (or wherever you create it) somewhere `MyObject` can access it, i.e.

```
object Main {
  var injector: Injector = null

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // make sure this happens before MyObject is accessed
    injector = Guice.createInjector(...)        
    ...
  }
}

object MyObject { 
  val foo = Main.injector.getInstance(classOf[Foo])
  foo.func()
}
```

If you don't even create the `Injector` yourself, but are using some framework which uses Guice, check if it gives you access to the `Injector`.

Comment: Thank you! We use Play Framework. I guess, I need to get the injector from Play.